# Human-chosen pseudo random variables that are not really random?

Tags: random

We're all familiar with not really random, human-chosen variables such as the disproportionate appearance of 37 when humans are asked to choose a number between 1 and 100, and for other cases (disproportionate selection of a particular one of four quadrants of a 2x2 grid, etc).  I'm sure I'd once read that these are called "[something] Variables."

Can anyone please provide me with the term for these variables?  Many thanks!

Comment: Ah, but human-selected values *are* random - they cannot be predicted with certainty.  However, they're not independent (humans tend to alternate high/low way more than truly independent sampling does), and they're not uniform (humans choose certain values disproportionately often, as you noted).

Comment: pjs - Your correction of my misuse of the term 'random' is spot on.  Can anyone out there provide me with the term for this non-uniform class of variable?  Thanks.

Comment: Questions about finding a name for a non-programming-related concept belong to https://english.stackexchange.com/, not here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Close it.  I'll try elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Random behavior is described by [probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution).  The [Uniform(0,1) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) is particularly important in computing because we have a variety of techniques to transform U(0,1)'s into other distributions. It's also easy to transform independent observations into non-independence via [distributional conditioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution).  I don't know of any general solution to go the other way. Bottom line is that it's much easier to deal with independent uniforms.

Because of those two observations, the gold standard for Pseudo-Random Number Generators (PRNGs) is to produce uniformly distributed values which *appear* to be independent. (I say "appear" because if each value follows its predecessor based on deterministic calculations, clearly they must be dependent in some fashion.) Humans do a terrible job in both regards.  To actually answer your question, values chosen by humans can be described as "non-uniform" and "not independent."

Some people might be tempted to say "uncorrelated" rather than "not independent," but they're not the same thing.  While independence always produces zero correlation, there are counter-examples where dependent random variables can have zero correlation.  In fact, most PRNGs are pretty good at producing uncorrelated values.